# При конвертировании QString в LPCSTR путь к диску заменяется случайным символом

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator

```
SHFILEOPSTRUCTA fileStruct;
ZeroMemory (&fileStruct, sizeof (SHFILEOPSTRUCT));

save_directory = save_directory.replace("/", "\\\\");
copy_directory = copy_directory.replace("/", "\\\\");
save_directory += "\\0";
copy_directory += "\\0";
save_directory.utf16();
copy_directory.utf16();

LPCSTR file_directory_trans = save_directory.toStdString().c_str();
LPCSTR copy_directory_trans = copy_directory.toStdString().c_str();
fileStruct.hwnd = GetDesktopWindow();
fileStruct.wFunc = FO_COPY;
fileStruct.pFrom = file_directory_trans;
fileStruct.pTo = copy_directory_trans;
fileStruct.fFlags = FOF_NOCONFIRMMKDIR;
```

Например: "D:/folder/test" меняется на "j \\folder\\test\0".

Answer (score 1):

Используйте лучше:

```
QString QDir::toNativeSeparators ( const QString & pathName )
```